# Find the pecentage between numbers in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set similar to below and I'm trying to group the data into percentage ranges. It doesn't have to be a single query.

| Number A | Number B |
| --- | --- |
| 105 | 100 |
| 115 | 134 |
| 120 | 110 |
| 140 | 170 |
| 140 | 190 |

I want to pull the rows where Number A is `0-6% +-` of Number B, so I would expect to only pull the first row in the example data set for this first bucket. I'm also trying to do the same thing but for `7-15%`, `16-20%` and so forth.

I've tried the following but my brain is fried so I don't feel confident that this is the right approach.
`Select * from table WHERE abs(NumberA/NumberB * 100) >= 0 and abs(NumberA/Number * 100) <= 6`

Edit: Trying to group the data above to find the total rows for each row. Using the case when approach recommended in the solutions. This is what I'm expecting to get:

| Count(*) | Segment |
| --- | --- |
| 2342 | 0-6% |
| 232 | 7-15% |
| 3232 | 16-20% |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to compute the range for each pair. For example:

```
select t.*, 
  case when abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.06 then '0-6%'
       when abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.15 then '6-15%'
       when abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.20 then '15-20%'
       else '20%+' end as segment       
from t
```

Result:

```
 A    B    SEGMENT 
 ---- ---- ------- 
 105  100  0-6%    
 115  134  15-20%  
 120  110  6-15%   
 140  170  20%+    
 140  190  20%+
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=282ea33608fccf52acff067c96dea6dd).

If you want to get only rows in the 0-6% range you can do:

```
select * 
from t
where abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.06
```

**EDIT - Grouping**

You can use the query above to `GROUP BY` the newly produce columns and count corresponding rows. For example:

```
select count(*) as cnt, segment
from (
  select t.*, 
    case when abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.06 then '0-6%'
         when abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.15 then '6-15%'
         when abs(b / a - 1.0) < 0.20 then '15-20%'
         else '20%+' end as segment       
  from t
) x
group by segment
```

See [Grouping Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=71c1807e6ee7350b5a711de18a9fdbcc).

Comment: ... I should have just come here first instead of beating my head against the wall for an hour.

Comment: looking at this again, I'm having a hard time grouping this correctly. I wanted to do a count(*) and group it like that so I have the total records for each range but it wants the A and B column in the group by which is creating more than the 4 rows I expected. Thoughts?

Comment: Please edit the question and add sample data and the expected result. It should be simple if we understand exactly what you need.

Comment: Updated with a table for clarity